# Mac kernel programming generic kernel extension prinf() not working

Tags: c, macos, kernel, kernel-extension, mach

I've followed the [Creating a Generic Kernel Extension with Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KEXTConcept/KEXTConceptKEXT/kext_tutorial.html) tutorial.

MyKext.c:

```
#include <sys/systm.h>
#include <mach/mach_types.h>

kern_return_t MyKext_start (kmod_info_t * ki, void * d)
{
    printf("MyKext has started.\n");
    return KERN_SUCCESS;
}

kern_return_t MyKext_stop (kmod_info_t * ki, void * d)
{
    printf("MyKext has stopped.\n");
    return KERN_SUCCESS;
}
```

I've also disabled the csrutil, which allow me to load my own kext.

```
# csrutil disable
```

When I load my own kext into kernel

```
$ sudo kextload -v /tmp/MyKext.kext
```

The result of printf() not write into /var/log/system.log.

I've also set boot-args

```
$ sudo nvram boot-args="original_contents debug=0x4"
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: first, you need to use kernal functions.  so `printf()` should be `printk()`

Comment: there are specific functions for writing to the system log.  They are: `openlog()`, `syslog()`, `closelog()`

Comment: @user3629249: What gives you that idea? `printf()` should work fine.

Comment: `printf()` is correct in macOS/OS X kernel extensions. `IOLog()` works identically, but is more usual in device drivers. What OS version are you running? As of 10.12, /var/log/system.log is no longer the correct place to look, you now need to look in the new system logging service, which you can access with the `log` command. `printk()` is a Linux thing, `syslog()` is for user space. Does your kext show up in the output of `kextstat`? Please don't use `kextload`, use `kextutil` instead, it has much better diagnostics.

Comment: you might have to look into console application and try putting your kernel extension name into the search textfield. all logs will be shown there for your application.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, since Sierra (10.12) at least, they reorganized the way the logs are written (iOS support?), so you cannot see it in `system.log` anymore. Still, in your Console application, you have in the sidebar a `Devices` section, where you can select your device (usually your Mac system) and see real-time log limited to "kernel" in the search box. So I can see these when using kext load/kextunload:

```
default 11:58:27.608228 +0200   kernel  MyKext has started.
default 11:58:34.446824 +0200   kernel  MyKext has stopped.
default 11:58:44.803350 +0200   kernel  MyKext has started.
```

There is no need for the `csrutil` and `nvram` changes.

**Important** For some freaky reason, I needed to restart the Console to reflect my messages changes, otherwise it has showing the ones (start & stop) from the previous build. Very strange indeed!

**Later** To recover old logs, try `sudo log collect --last 1d` and open the result with `Console`([more here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/273293/why-kernel-log-is-empty)).

Comment: Comment about console just resolved the issue with my logs..... Still don't get why apple does not mention it anywhere... thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to necro-post, but I found it useful to use `log(1)` with one of its many commands (as suggested by @pmdj in the comments above) rather than use Console. From the manual:

> log -- Access system wide log messages created by os_log, os_trace and other log-
>        ging systems.

For example, one can run:

```
log stream
```

to see real-time output of the system, including `printf()` from the MacOS kernel extension.